# No Cosmos DB Graph database Emulator

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases

I have a Xamain application that used the Azure cosmos db, both the document API and graph API.

To avoid to pay (it cost a lot for a home user), I use the "Azure Cosmos DB Emulator", but it only supports document database!

So, is there some solutions to have a local Graph database, compatible with Azure Graph API, that I can use locally?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Emulator release we're planning for the Microsoft Ignite conference will come with support for all Cosmos DB APIs, including the Graph API. Please keep an eye out for this release.

Comment: Hi David, I have download and install the last version, but I have find no way to use the Graph API. Is it normal ? Thx

Comment: I have see that on the MS web site, they have update the page and claims that we can use Gremlin API, but I can't find any way to use it. I have find no instructions, the Azure Explorer does not show anything ! See, they claims we can use the Gremlin API : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator

Answer (score 0):

From : [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator) and [apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.4.](https://archive.apache.org/dist/tinkerpop/3.3.4)

```
Gremlin API
Start emulator from an administrator command prompt with "/EnableGremlinEndpoint". Alternatively you can also set the environment variable AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_GREMLIN_ENDPOINT=true

Install apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.4.

In the emulator's Data Explorer create a database "db1" and a collection "coll1"; for the partition key, choose "/name"

Run the following commands in a regular command prompt window:


cd /d C:\sdk\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.4-bin\apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-console-3.3.4

copy /y conf\remote.yaml conf\remote-localcompute.yaml
notepad.exe conf\remote-localcompute.yaml
  hosts: [localhost]
  port: 8901
  username: /dbs/db1/colls/coll1
  password: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
  connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: false}
  serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0,
  config: { serializeResultToString: true  }}

bin\gremlin.bat
In the Gremlin shell run the following commands to connect to the Gremlin endpoint:


:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote-localcompute.yaml
:remote console
:> g.V()
:> g.addV('person1').property(id, '1').property('name', 'somename1')
:> g.addV('person2').property(id, '2').property('name', 'somename2')
:> g.V()
```

You can use it via emulator but you should not have any Explorer View